# Docker run in gitlab-ci

Tags: docker, gitlab

this is my gitlab-ci.yml:

```
codescan:
 image: docker:latest
 stage: deploy
 script:
  - "docker run 192.168.17.5:5200/codescan:latest /start.sh"
```

The start.sh is now just a echo-command for testing purposes.

But in the gitlab log I cant see the echo:

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to `echo` just a string or a value of a variable?

Comment: just a string, just a test to see if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use `codescan:latest` image like below:

```
codescan:
 image: 192.168.17.5:5200/codescan:latest
 stage: deploy
 script:
  - /start.sh
```